# ZF2: Restful and image combination

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, rest, zend-framework2

I am building a site using Zend Framework 2 and AngularJS. I have a restful webservice running in ZF2 and I use AngularJS on the client to access that webservice.

Now I want to add a photo album to my site, and I have the following question around this subject:

- **How do I give the images to AngularJS? Should I just return a json with the links to the directories on the server. And then load it using `<img src="" />`, or are there other, beter ways?**

Answer (score 1):

You can also send the image back by modifying the response and then returning it from your action, like this

```
$data = //Get the file information
$response = $this->getEvent()->getResponse();
$response->setStatusCode(Response::STATUS_CODE_200);
$response->getHeaders()->addHeaderLine('Content-Type: ' . $data['file_mime'])
                                    ->addHeaderLine('Content-Length: ' . $data['file_size'])
                                    ->addHeaderLine('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $data['file_name'] . '"');
$response->setContent($data['file_data']); // or stream file data
return $response;
```